# get a specific taxonomy term name

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I need to print a specific term with its id. I get that for categories with this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link(1); ?>" title="<?php echo get_cat_name(1);?>"><?php echo get_cat_name(1);?></a>
```

… where 1 is the id I have to print. Is there something like the following?

```
<?php echo get_term_link(1); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo get_term_name(1); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`get_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) to get the name, slug, or description:

```
$term = get_term( 1, 'taxonomy_slug' );
// Name
echo $term->name;

// Link
echo get_term_link(1, 'taxonomy_slug'); 
// OR
echo get_term_link( $term );
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this question as being answered, so it goes off the list of unanswered questions. :)

Comment: I'm sorry! I am beginner and especially my English :P:P
i've marked it rigth?

Comment: Beside my answer there should be a checkmark ✓ <- Click it! :D

Comment: ok! i did it :)

Comment: This is a long and inconvenient solution for something that has now a builtin method for, see my answer above.

Comment: Glad to hear there's a built in way to do this now. I think you're being a bit dramatic with a 2-line solution being long/inconvenient, though @MaximeCulea

Comment: @EricHolmes ok you are a bit right, the idea is also that using a magic getter is not intend to be in my opinion :/
Also as there are new methods, there is no point using the past ones that could lead to incomprehension in heavier projects, just saying ;)

Answer (score 8):

Since WP 2.3.0, there is an API to get term's fields : [`get_term_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_field/).

So, I would rather use **`<?php get_term_field( 'key', $term ); ?>`** which is pretty handy :

- `key` : could be multiple : link, name, etc.
- `$term` : can either be the term_id or the \WP_Term object.

Comment: I think this should be the selected answer.  Being that the orginial question assumes you have the TERM ID, using this method only requires one line.
Simple and to the point!